# How to determine the limit of $f(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{2x^6y}{x^8+y^4+5x^4y^2}$ as $\mathbf{x} \rightarrow \mathbf{0}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

How do I determine the limit of $f(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{2x^6y}{x^8+y^4+5x^4y^2}$ as $\mathbf{x} \rightarrow \mathbf{0}$, where $f:\mathbb{R^2}-\{(0,0)\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Following the suggestion I received in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116384/how-to-guess-that-fx-y-has-no-limit) answer, I tried to convert the function into polar coordinates, and this is what I got:

$$ f(r,\theta) = \frac{r^32\cos^6(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{r^4\cos^8(\theta)+\sin^4(\theta)+5r^2\cos^4(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)}$$

I am not aware of how the above expression can be further simplified further. What should I do next?

Later on the question also asks if $f(\mathbf{x})y$ has a limit as $\mathbf{x}\rightarrow 0$.

Please advise on the method that I should use to solve this kind of problem.

EDIT:

The solution given is:

1. $f(\mathbf{x})$ has no limit as $\mathbf{x}\rightarrow \mathbf{0}$
2. the limit of $f(\mathbf{x})y$ is $0$ as  $\mathbf{x}\rightarrow \mathbf{0}$

The solution simply lists the steps to show why the above is true. It does not discuss the approach. In fact, it starts by saying some experimentation is usually required and did not elaborate further. As such, if I was faced with a similar question in the future, I doubt that I will be able to make progress.

Therefore, how should I approach this sort of question i.e. to determine the limit of a two variable rational function as it tends to some point. What observations should I make to determine the right course of action? Even if there is no set way, what heuristics can I follow to help arrive at the answer?

I've not seen any text discuss a strategy for these kind of questions, so I would also appreciate it if someone can direct me to an online resource (if available). If it helps to narrow the scope of the answer, I am doing an introductory real analysis course.

Comment: do you mean when $(x,y) \to 0$ or do you want to know the limit as a function of $y$ when $x \to 0$?

Comment: in this case he use the notation.  $\mathb{x}=(x,y)$.

Comment: Going for all path y = mx the limit is zero. Is it enough?

Answer (score 1):

Because in the denominator there's a symmetry between $y$ and $x^2$, it's natural to look at the behavior of the function along parabolas $y = ax^2$. Then your function becomes
$$f(x,ax^2) = {2ax^6x^2 \over x^8 + (ax^2)^4 + 5x^4(ax^2)^2}$$
$$= {2a \over 1 + a^4 + 5a^2}$$
So $f(x,y)$ is constant on each such parabola, but the constant varies with $a$. Since all of these parabolas contain the origin, you get different limits as you approach the origin along each parabola. Hence the overall limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Quite nice proof!

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by symmetry around between teh $y$ and $x^2$ in the denominator? Do you mean that they are interchangeable? And since the limit of $f(\mathbf{x})$ exists as $\mathbf{X}\rightarrow 0$, what method will you use to arrive at the answer?

Comment: The denominator is $(x^2)^4 + (y)^4 + 5 (x^2)^2(y)^2$. If you switch the roles of $x^2$ and $y$ this expression doesn't change. And the limit doesn't exist, as I explained in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This expression does not have a limit as ${x}$ tends to zero, and hence no method you try to use will not work.
In order to show it has no limit you only have to come up with two different paths by which you can reach two different limits.

Try looking at $y=0$ identically and $x \rightarrow 0$ on one hand.

And at $y=x^2$, $x\rightarrow 0$ on the other hand.

Answer (score 0):

Since $y$ cannot be zero then
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{2x^6y}{x^8+y^4+5x^4y^2}=\frac{0}{y^4}=0$$
Multiplying $f$ by $y$ makes no difference to the limit.

Comment: The answers by Luis and Zarrax allow $y$ to approach zero as $x$ approaches zero.  Isn't this excluded in the posing of the question?

Comment: No he means as the vector ${\bf x} = (x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow your steps. I thought you just divided the numerator and denominator by $y$ but this does not seem to be the case.